Slack block kit multi_user_select - no groups?
I want users to be able to select groups from the Slack Modal. They can select users using the multi_users_select but it does not show groups. Is there anyway to also show groups in multi_users_select?
Tried adding a multi_users_select to the form but this only shows users. Same with user_select. I'd like to also show slack groups from the same select menu
